# Is there a way to set "now playing" using the spotify app api?

Tags: spotify

In the spotify app api is there a way to set the "now playing" playlist without interrupting the currently playing track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The currently playing track and the thing it's playing from *together* make "Now playing". By definition, you can't change "now playing" without interrupting what's playing.

If you want to modify what plays *after* the current track, watch for the relevant event on the player object - when the current track ends, you can then change what plays next seamlessly.